# What do you call a person who always compares before buying anything?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage, american-english

What do you call a person who always compares before buying anything ?

Comment: A "smart shopper"?

Comment: This question lacks detail. Do you want to know if a specific term exists, or do you want a complimentary/derogatory term? How would you use this term? Can you please supply a sentence where this term would be used.

Comment: Questions that lack context, research, and effort tend to fall flat on their faces here, in other words they get shut down.

Comment: i want to know the specific term that exists

Answer (score 0):

How about 'a discerning shopper'.  A fussy or well-informed buyer. A careful buyer.

Or an 'intelligent shopper'.

You can even buy a robot now on Amazon, which is an intelligent shopper:

[https://www.amazon.com/Alfie-Voice-Controlled-Intelligent-Shopper/dp/B01JV7YWHY](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01JV7YWHY)